# Can the "C:\Build" folder be removed?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-storage-server

Our Windows Storage Server (Windows Storage Server 2008) has a "Build" folder at the root of the OS volume (in this case C:). The folder is 3.5GB in size and has a filerepository folder within it that seems like it may be full of packages from the OEM build of Storage Server. Does anyone have any thoughts on whether this folder needs to be kept around or if it can be removed?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is known issue for Windows Storage Server 2008.

According to 
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd904408(v=ws.10).aspx you can delete Builds folder.